# Etymology of 'wipe the floor with'?

Tags: etymology, idioms

If you 'wipe the floor with' someone, you defeat them easily.  Searching on Google, I can only see explanations of what this idiom means, but not how it came about.  What caused people to start using this phrase in this way?

Comment: I can guess, but I have no proof: I bet it's to do with bar brawls, in so far as a bar's floor always needs cleaning, and once you've incapacitated someone, you can then clean the floor with them.

Comment: I could buy the literal explanation above, but could it not just be likening the defeated person to a dirty rag; worthy only of wiping muck off the floor? I'm sure with a bit of thought, all kinds of "smack talk" can be thought of along those lines. "He made him his bitch" for instance, suggesting the defeated is now a servant or similar in that connotation.

Comment: I always thought it meant to wipe the floor "with" someone, as in together. I thought it meant friendship in hard times! But actually it means sth quite different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[According to](http://books.google.com/books?id=1NjWAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA61&hl=en&ei=TnAlTrmUO8bu0gH-opTnCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA) *A dictionary of slang, jargon and cant* by Barrère and Leland (1897), it means that "one man has thrashed another so completely as to have taken him like a broom or mop, and swept or cleaned the floor with him."

[image]

(Rather cheekily, both usage examples there are from poems by Leland himself.)

Comment: The askee said as much. This does not contribute anything new to the question. It is not an answer.